# Signal segmentation with overlaps

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have some signals. They are all the same length (`N = 1024`). I have to break each into `Ns = 7` segments with `L = 256` points so there will be 50% overlapping. `S = randi(10,[4 N]);` can be thought as 4 signals. I was thinking about saving the break points in a vector (calculate them manually!) and using two loops to save the new `4 * Ns = 28` signals in a cell, but it won't be a good solution. So is there a quicker way like `reshape`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `256` points rather, because with 253 points don't think they add upto 1024?

Comment: @Divakar, thanks, I corrected it (but it says 253 in my book, it can be a mistake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Parameters
N = 1024
L = 256
num_seg = 2*(N/L)-1

%// Indices for the first signal with each column representing one segment.
%// Thus, there must be 7 columns, representing those 7 segments in a signal.
signal1_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[1:L]',[0:num_seg-1]*L/2);  %//'

%// Indices for the all the signals in a 3D array with each 3D slice
%// representing one signal 
allsignals_idx = bsxfun(@plus,signal1_idx,permute([0:size(S,1)-1]*N,[1 3 2]))

%// Index into the input array to create a 3D array output 
St = S'  %//'
out = St(allsignals_idx)
```

How to interpret the output, `out`:

- Each column in each slice of `out` would be one segment from one signal.
- The number of columns in each 3D slice would be the number of segments in a signal.
- Each 3D slice of `out` would be for each signal.

Sample run for `N = 16` & `L = 4`:

```
>> S
S =
     6    10     9     2     3     1     8     8     4     5     7    10     5     8    10     9
     8     9     5     4     4     4     7     2     9     4     3     7     4     7     4     9
     5     4     5    10     7    10     7     9     2     7     2     8     9     9     1     4
     7     3     2     1     1    10     3     1     8     3     4    10     4     4     4    10
>> out
out(:,:,1) =
     6     9     3     8     4     7     5
    10     2     1     8     5    10     8
     9     3     8     4     7     5    10
     2     1     8     5    10     8     9
out(:,:,2) =
     8     5     4     7     9     3     4
     9     4     4     2     4     7     7
     5     4     7     9     3     4     4
     4     4     2     4     7     7     9
out(:,:,3) =
     5     5     7     7     2     2     9
     4    10    10     9     7     8     9
     5     7     7     2     2     9     1
    10    10     9     7     8     9     4
out(:,:,4) =
     7     2     1     3     8     4     4
     3     1    10     1     3    10     4
     2     1     3     8     4     4     4
     1    10     1     3    10     4    10
```

Comment: Thanks, It is exactly what I wanted (without loops).

Comment: @Kamtal You don't really need to save it in a cell array, right? I mean cells eventually would slow you down.

Comment: Yeah I don't, it was just how I imagined things go! but apparently they can go much easier.

Comment: Beautiful :) Seems like `Bsxfun` could do anything if dealt correctly (Y)

Comment: @SanthanSalai I like to think of it as *transcendental* ;)